# Understanding this piece of example C++ code (class definition)

Tags: c++

Found this code in an Introduction to C++ course presentation.
It is refering to working with classes as Data Types.
The thing I don't understand is line 5, the Bounded_Stack function definition.
What does the ":" means there and later the "stack_ (len), top_ (0)".
I can understand basic C++ but have never encountered this sintax before.

The code:

```
#include "Vector.h"
template <class T>
class Bounded_Stack {
public:
Bounded_Stack (int len) : stack_ (len), top_ (0) {}
// . . .
private:
Vector<T> stack_;
int top_;
};
```

Comment: Read about [member initialization lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

Comment: I believe you need to read more about C++ in general. `Bounded_Stack(int)` is not a function in this context; in fact it doesn't have a return type. It is a constructor with initialization list. If you don't know what these terms mean you need a book or tutorial about C++ classes definitions. I always recommend Koenig's Accelerated C++ for a good intro.

Comment: Thank you. I've found my answer already thanks to @zenith . I know it is a constructor I just expressed it loosely, led by my Spanish-molded mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the [constructor initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). It initializes the member variables of the class.

For example the `Bounded_Stack(int)` constructor in your example initializes the member `stack_` to `len` and `top_` to `0`.

Comment: No, it's called a "member initializer list".

Comment: But "constructor initialization list" is more descriptive. "Member initializer list" sounds like an initializer list used to initialize a single member.

Comment: The problem is that an "initialization list" is something else entirely (e.g.,  in `std::vector<int> x{1, 2, 3, 4};`, the `{1, 2, 3, 4}` part is an initialization list).

Comment: I thought those were called "initializer lists", probably because of the [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). Am I wrong?

Comment: Both names are used for them. I'm less concerned about "initializer" vs. "initialization" than the "member" being there to distinguish the two.